# GSAP not working using NPM in node/express/ejs project

Tags: node.js, ejs, gsap

I have a node.js project. I'm building a website using EJS templates. I want to use GSAP for my animations. I created a /public/js/gsap-homepage.js file that I linked to my /views/homepage.ejs.

When I used the GSAP3 CDN everything works. But when I want to try it using NPM it doesn't work.
I installed gsap using `npm install gsap`. Then in gsap-homepage.js I imported gsap as per the GSAP docs `import { gsap } from "gsap"`. I even tried `import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap"` and `const gsap = require("gsap/dist/gsap").gsap`. But none of them work.

How to make GSAP work in npm. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey Suraj. It's hard to say exactly what the issue is based on the above info. What's wrong with just using the CDN?

Comment: Hi Zach. There's nothing wrong with using the CDN. That's working fine. But I was wondering what if I'm just developing locally and don't have internet access. That happens sometimes and I don't want that to interrupt me. I could just download the GSAP zip but I was curious why NPM wasn't working.

Comment: It's impossible to say given the provided information. Maybe you could try to recreate the issue using something like StackBlitz or CodeSandbox?

Comment: It doesn't work because 'require' or 'import' suppose node running server-side and you're trying to run an animation script 'browser-side'. I have the same problem myself and haven't found the solution. CDN works unless you want to use Premium Gsap plugins that require installation and are not available via CDN.

Comment: Use as  ( UMD / CommonJS )  works form me 
`const { gsap } = require("gsap/dist/gsap");`

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded my server-side rendered React app from gsap@2.1.3 to gsap@3.6.0. I installed it with this command: `npm install gsap@3.6.0`

In the previous version was using their `umd` subdirectory. But I wanted to try to use their main build. I was able import the base library fine using `import gsap from 'gsap'`. However, when I tried to import the `ScrollToPlugin` I got an error.

I ended up having to go back to use the `umd` method. For the new version that meant importing like so:

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap/dist/gsap'
import { ScrollToPlugin } from 'gsap/dist/ScrollToPlugin'
```

https://github.com/greensock/GSAP
https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation#npm